# Flutter 1.17 update not finding mobx dependencies

Tags: flutter, mobx

[Error in finding mobx dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MmHU.png)

After updating both flutter and dart i m using both latest SDK when i added mobx dependencies in my pub spec.yml i got this error  "A package may not list itself as a dependency."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the name of your project is the same of the plugin. You can see a related problem [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/181).
I recomend you to change the name of your project to prevent this conflict.

Comment: Yes,it works,project name and plugin both name are same thats why it was showing that issue.Thanks a lot